# string.search find words contained in input

Tags: c++, string

i want to create a function that search's a string saved from the cin getline for multiple words. i have found an example which i will give below how ever it only search's for one word.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string sentence = "My scanner is not working.";
cout << "sentence: " << sentence << endl;

string search;
size_t pos;

search = "printer";
pos = sentence.find(search);
if (pos != string::npos)
    cout << "sentence contains " << search << endl;
else
    cout << "sentence does not contain " << search << endl;

search = "scanner";
pos = sentence.find(search);
if (pos != string::npos)
    cout << "sentence contains " << search << endl;
else
    cout << "sentence does not contain " << search << endl;

return 0;
}
```

how do i search for multiple words??

Comment: for example if i type in "do you have a sword" i want it to search for the words "you" "have" "sword" that way it dosnt have to be "do you have a sword" it could also be "have you got a sword" or even " have you got the sword"

Answer (score -1):

How about using a loop?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sentence = "My scanner is not working.";
    cout << "sentence: " << sentence << endl;

    string search[] =
    { "printer", "scanner", "working" };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(search) / sizeof(search[0]); i++)
    {
        size_t pos = sentence.find(search[i]);
        if (pos != string::npos)
            cout << "sentence contains " << search[i] << endl;
        else
            cout << "sentence does not contain " << search[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there a method to put the string search[] = into an if statement that way i can create a number of statements? if that makes sence