# searching a string for particular words

Tags: windows, codeblocks

i want to create like a very basic AI for a console game. i need a function that will recognize 2 or 3 words within a string created via cin. any help would be greatly appreciated as iv been at this for a while now and cant seem to find a solution.

Comment: Post what you have so far. If nothing, the simplest way is to search the input string for each of a number of target strings using `string::find()`. You can find info on that here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/. A more elegant solution is to use regular expressions to search for each possible word - see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: I see now that you have asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26836943/21945) before. What was wrong with the answers provided?

Comment: i have asked this before, so i guess you have seen what code i have so far, the thing is i can only seem to have that function once, iv tried in a number of ways but i keep having either errors or it doesn't quite work properly

Comment: i have this that works, but i cant seem to search for more then one word at a time

Comment: Please add your code to the question, not as an answer.

Comment: As suggested, regular expressions would allow you to search for multiple patterns (your target words) in a single call - see the reference already provided. Otherwise you can use an array of strings containing the target words, and _loop_ over that array calling `sentence.find()` for each target word.

Comment: sorry, i am still getting used to the site and how to use it appropriately. iv been messing around with my code and i seem to have managed to get it working the way i want for now. and as for array's thanks for the suggestion, its something i will have to play around with, as i am sure i could improve the way i am doing the sentence.find at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 //-------------------------------------------globals
string sentence;





int main()
{
getline(cin, sentence);

string search;
size_t pos;

search = "hi";
pos = sentence.find(search);
if (pos != string::npos)
    cout << "hello sir " << endl;
else
search = "cya";
    pos = sentence.find("cya");
if (pos != std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "goodbye sir " << endl;
else
search = "goodbye";
    pos = sentence.find("goodbye");
if (pos != std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "shuting down sir " << endl;
else



return 0;
}
```

what i would like is to have the initial search look for other words such as hello hey, and so forth, and the similer thing with the others